# Can I add a Golang Compiler to Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: go, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines-build-task

We are going to use Visual Studio Team Services for a project.  We are using VSTS Git as our repository.  A portion of this project is written in Golang.  We want to enable CI and build/test all code at check in.  I have been learning more about extensions, the build agents and build process within VSTS.  I see in the marketplace there are options for Android, iOS and other platforms (but not GoLang).  Can anyone start me on the path to creating a custom extension or build definition for Golang? How can I create a custom extension to enable automated builds at check-in of GoLang code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes but I would look at it a bit differently. There is no need to add anything to VSTS, you just need golang/the go compiler installed on your build agent and then you can set up a job using MSBuild like any other MSFT supported language which invokes the Go compiler with your sources. Basically, write an msbuild script who's sole job is to invoke the go compiler with the target sources.

Here are MSBuild docs on the Exec task which is what you'd use to kick off your build; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx

Comment: How would you go about installing the Go compiler on the VSTS build agent? As far as I can tell the VSTS build agent come with [a lot of software](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted#software) installed and there is no way to install a Go compiler.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know in order to add the Go compiler you need to setup a [private agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/agents/agents#install) or install it on the fly using a build task like the [tool installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/tasks#tool-installers)